# Connecting text relating to array object: how and where?

Tags: javascript, arrays, file, external

I am working on a project in which there are a few ways I need to connect an object (a string, specifically) in an array to an additional bit of text amounting to a few sentences.

Currently I have a function that creates the array and populates it with values (both strings and numbers) related to the game being played:

```js
/* store names by male and female for selection later */
var aliasM = ["Spike", "Mike", "Pops", "Noodles", "Shorty"];
var aliasF = ["Shanna", "Rose", "Sugar", "Alana"];

function aliasSelector() {
  if (Math.random() <= 0.55) {
    alias = aliasM[Math.floor(Math.random() * aliasM.length)];
    var mTook = aliasM.indexOf(alias);
    aliasM.splice(mTook, 1)
  } else {
    alias = aliasF[Math.floor(Math.random() * aliasF.length)];
    var fTook = aliasF.indexOf(alias);
    aliasF.splice(fTook, 1);
  }
  return alias;
}

function playerGen(name, alias, turns, mech, cash, credit) {
  this.name = name;
  this.alias = aliasSelector();
  this.turns = 0;
  this.mech = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 5);
  this.cash = 1000 + Math.round(Math.random() * 1000);
  this.credit = Math.round(Math.random() * 2000);
}

/*Next we create array objects for each player */
function nameCheck() {
  p1 = document.getElementById("p1Entry").value;
  if (p1 !== "") {
    playerList.push(new playerGen(p1));
  }
  /* and so on */
}
```

What I'd like to include is a short description of each alias name. So if the player gets the Alias "Spike", there is a short paragraph *someplace* telling us about Spike.

I'm not sure how to make this connection without including the sentence in the array. I'm thinking a conditional of some kind might work or creating a notation of some kind that connects the name to the paragraph, stored as a variable spikeInfo.  I think this last method makes the most sense, something like:

```js
var SpikeInfo = "Spike is an HVAC specialist from Fresno who....";
```

Can this stuff be stored in another file, or is there value in doing so? Would that be a .txt file, or another .js file?

Comment: Are you using this in a webpage or elsewhere?

Comment: Right now it's in a web page. I'm trying to bump up my level of programming to enhance my teaching (I teach high school multimedia) and to do some hobby type stuff related to my love of motorcycles.. So I may try to pour this into a PhoneGap setup and create  a mobile app, though I've gotten the impression that doing a true app would best be done in native language of the target device. This is a start in the right direction in terms of learning programming. I hope.

Comment: in the big picture, I'd like to be able to update the content to add different scenarios and characters into the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wish to do this on a webpage, and if you store the information on the alias as a file called `nameBio.html` or similar, you can use [AHAH](http://www.xfront.com/microformats/AHAH.html) to fetch and insert the bio. AHAH will fetch the file and insert it into a HTML element. If you want to collect the text after you load it in, simply fetch the `innerHTML` of the element you fetched it into, or modify the AHAH code.

Here's an example

HTML

```
<div id="name"></div>
<div id="bio"></div>
```

JS

```
//Let's assume your randomly picked name is stored in a variable called randNm 
var fileName = randNm + "Bio.html";
ahah(filename,bio)

document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = randNm;
var bioText = document.getElementById("bio").innerHTML
```

nmBio.html:

```
<!--This Bio Should Be Stored Like This -->
<p>
    Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet Is Absolute Gibberish And Not Even Close To Real Latin...
</p>
```

If the name was "Spike" then this code would fetch a file called "SpikeBio.html" Now you have you name and the relevant bio fetched and displayed, along with the bio stored in a variable. This is certainly not a neat or elegant solution, but it works with little code.

You could also do it having two arrays:

JS:

```
var names = ["name1","name2",...];
var bios = ["BioForName1","BioForName2",...];
var whichName = Math.floor(Math.random()*names.length-1);
var chosenName = names[whichName];
var chosenBio = bios[whichName];
```

This assumes that the bio for a name is in the same position in its array as the name in its array.

Comment: Of the two methods you point to here, I think the first is most efficient (though new to me), simply because it only loads the info needed. In my initial work I have maybe ten each male and female identities (assigned regardless of player's gender), but if I get really going I'll be adding to the list significantly.

Comment: On the other hand, your Javascript only version is pretty clean as well and allows me to think towards a true app from my Javascript. My current version removes the alias name from the array once it is selected, and (I think?) transfers its value to the players array. Same works for the bio as shown in your sample.  
Thanks!

Comment: Deep, I went with the Js version. I had previously had part of the name selector split randomly by gender, but the only place where gender mattered is in the name and bio, which can contain the gender. So I combined the two arrays (for m&f) into one so it would be easier to grab the bio from the separate list as you suggest. Works smoothly. 
I suspect my concerns about the number of characters in a more developed version may be moot.

Answer (score 0):

I would include the paragraph in the array using an object literal like

```
 [{Name:"spike",Bio:"foo"}, ...]
```

You can store it as Json and load it using the built in js Jason object.

Comment: Thanks Nick: This appears to enable me to keep the data all in one place. I think I've seen some examples that allow the array to be created from a list referencing the array through dot-notation, which also makes a nice readable format.
I had to go look up more about Json. While I'm relatively new to Javascript, the leap to Json (which I've heard of and is in a text I'm using to learn from) is not too far and appears pretty simple (by design apparently). Thanks for the direction.